# zerorpc module throwing error in python 2.7

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, zerorpc

I'm using zerorpc module to communicate between node and python.Im able to call python script from node but not getting the passed arguments in python instead getting error as "TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but memoryview found".
node version is v4.4.5 and the python version is 2.7

python script

```
    import zerorpc
    c = zerorpc.Client()
    c.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:4242")
    print (c.hello("RPC"))
```

Node script

```
   var zerorpc = require("zerorpc");
   var server = new zerorpc.Server({
   hello: function(name, reply) {
      reply(null, "Hello, " + name);
   }
  });

  server.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:4242");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a common problem with the pure python implementation of msgpack instead of the native library binding. Double check the installation of the msgpack package:

```
pip install --reinstall msgpack
```

Feel free to try this branch from the repo to see if it helps, I know I tried working around this problem, but I don't guarantee anything: https://github.com/0rpc/zerorpc-python/tree/python3.4

(and yes, this branch is for both python>=2.6 & python>=3.4)